# django no reverse match

Tags: python, django, web-applications

ok I was getting help from a kind person on this problem and would like to see if anyone can help here is my code.
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^venues/(?P<venue_id>\d+)/$','venues.views.venue', name='venue'),
```

views.py

```
def venue(request,venue_id):
venue= get_object_or_404(VenueProfile,
                           venue__pk=venue_id).select_related('venue')

return render_to_response('venues/venueprofile',{'venue',venue},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
{% load url from future %}
{% for v in venues %}
    {% with ven=v.venue profile=v %}
<a href="{% url 'venue' venue_id=venue.pk %}">{{ven.name}}</a>
```

now when I try to use this i get Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'venue_id': ''}' not found.Can anybody please help me here, and please keep in mind I left out some code like the {{venues}} object defined in a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `venue` object in your template is none, so it doesn't have a `pk`. In your template you aren't passing any `venues` object either. Perhaps simplifying your code a bit will help:

Adjusting your view method a bit:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def venue(request,venue_id):
    the_venue = get_object_or_404(Venue,pk=venue_id)
    return render(request,'venues/venueprofile',{'venue',the_venue})
```

Your template:

```
{% load url from future %}
<a href="{% url 'venue' venue_id=venue.pk %}">{{venue.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of venue.pk is empty string, since it does not match your regular expression, it is showing no reverse match problem.

```
{% load url from future %}
{% for v in venues %}
    {% with ven=v.venue profile=v %}
<a href="{% url 'venue' venue_id=venue.pk %}">{{ven.name}}</a> # Problem is that venue.pk is empty string
```

> Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'venue_id': ''}'
>   check here value of venue_id is ''.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
{% url 'venue' venue_id=venue.pk %}
```

with

```
{% url 'venue' venue_id=ven.pk %}
```