# Django:cms no reverse match error

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

Iam getting the error as follows.

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'pages-details-by-slug' with arguments
>   '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: [u'zh-cn/(?P[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$']

i have set the content management system(CMS) slug in the admin page, it started occurring i think after i tried to install haystack on the same server. Any suggestions?
I am using

> Django==1.6.11, django-cms==3.0

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170367/django-no-reverse-match? Did it help?

Comment: `{'slug': ''}` means that either an object has no slug, or the object is missing from the template context. It's impossible to help any more from the information you have given.